# Scheduling latency of Android sensors handlers

Tags: android, linux-kernel, scheduling, linux-device-driver

rather than an answer I'm looking for an idea here.

I'd like to measure the scheduling latency of sensor sampling in Android. In particular I want to measure the time from the sensor interrupt request to when the bottom half, which is in charge of the data read, is executed.

The bottom half already has, besides the data read, a timestamping instruction. Indeed samples are collected by applications (being java or native, no difference) as a tuple [measurement, timestamp].
The timestamp follows the clock source `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t);`
So assuming that the bottom-half is not preempted, somehow this timestamp gives an indication of the task scheduling instant. What is missing is a direct or indirect way to find out its corresponding irq instant.

Safely assume that we can ask any sampling rate to the sensor. The driver skeleton is the following (Galaxy's S3 gyroscope)

```
err = request_threaded_irq(data->client->irq, NULL,
        lsm330dlc_gyro_interrupt_thread\
        , IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING | IRQF_ONESHOT,\
            "lsm330dlc_gyro", data);

static irqreturn_t lsm330dlc_gyro_interrupt_thread(int irq\
    , void *lsm330dlc_gyro_data_p)  {
    ...
    struct lsm330dlc_gyro_data *data = lsm330dlc_gyro_data_p;
    ...
    res = lsm330dlc_gyro_read_values(data->client,
        &data->xyz_data, data->entries);
    ...
    input_report_rel(data->input_dev, REL_RX, gyro_adjusted[0]);
    input_report_rel(data->input_dev, REL_RY, gyro_adjusted[1]);
    input_report_rel(data->input_dev, REL_RZ, gyro_adjusted[2]);
    input_sync(data->input_dev);
    ...
}
```

The key constraint is that I need to (well, I only have enough resources to) perform this measurement from user-space, on a commercial device, without toucing and recompliling the kernel. Hopefully with a limited mpact on the experiment accuracy. I don't know if such an experiment is possible with this constraint and so far I couldn't figure out any reasonable method.

I might consider also recompiling the kernel if the experiment then becomes straightforward.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you be willing to open the phone? If yes then you can always probe the gyroscope irq pin on an oscilloscope?...

Answer (score 0):

First Its not possible to perform this measurement without touching the kernel.

Second I didnt see any bottom half configured in your ISR code.

Third if at all Bottom half is scheduled and kernel can be recompiled , you can sample jiffie value in ISR and again resample it in bottom half. take the difference between the two samples and subtract that offset  from timestamp that is exported to U-space.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's the solution I'd thought about if only I could recompile. The bottom half is the threaded interrupt handler, more info [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/302043/)